# cant display data from mysql db in a html page

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

here is the routing code:

```
@app.route("/notice_disp" , methods=['POST','GET'])     
def notice_disp():          
    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()    
    result=cur.execute("SELECT * FROM notices")    
    if result > 0:     
             data=cur.fetchall()      
             cur.close()     
                   return render_template('notice_disp.html',data = data )
```

here is the html code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>notice id</th>
            <th>notice name</th>
            <th>notice</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
        {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{row.0}}</td>
            <td>{{row.1}}</td>
            <td>{{row.2}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

output in html page:
[cant display the data, i have data stored in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pkY7.png)

Answer (score 1):

`fetchall()` returns a list of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple). Therefore you have to use brackets to access each tuple's elements:

```
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but im still getting no output.

Comment: Can you take a look at the content of `data` with a debugger before passing it to `render_template()`?